# Why OpenSuse (ver.13) does no install a lot of basic softwares for development

Tags: opensuse

Why OpenSuse (ver.13) does no install a lot of basic softwares for development. But their GUI and widget softwares are all over the place.

For example, there is no `gcc` installed. there is no `make` installed. There is no `git` installed. There is no basic kernel header installed.

So after fresh installation of Suse. I have to manually install a lot of things in order just to compile one of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developing is not the first thing that comes to mind when installing an OS. Doing so would just drive promising new users away from the Linux community. The focus would definitely by on getting a working system running right away, and then the other requirements specific to the user.

Answer (score 8):

This is quite a bit like asking "why does OpenSUSE not install any software for orbital mechanics calculations by default?". Just to pick some other software category that lots of users would have no need for (and not knowing whether they *do* or not install any such software by default).

Each distribution will have a set of default packages that get installed when the user does not make any specific choices. For a desktop-oriented distribution, that might include things like LibreOffice and Firefox but no development software like GCC, binutils, make and so on. For a development-oriented distribution the default set of software is likely to be different. A distribution geared toward servers will have yet other defaults. And so on.

Some distributions will have prerequisites that others don't. For example, you'd be hard pressed to get to a working Gentoo installation *without* having those exact development packages installed, whether or not you plan to use it for any sort of software development. A Red Hat installation is unlikely to install packages that help you deal with software packaged in .deb archives, whereas on Debian and derivates you have to go out of your way to be able to deal with .rpm archives. And so on.

Fortunately, as you have found, it tends to be quite easy to add the relevant packages to the system installation.

Considering that a large fraction of users won't do development on their systems, the ease with which development packages can be added and the fact that SuSE has pretty much always been geared more toward the desktop than anything else, it's likely that the OpenSUSE maintainers simply decided that those who want development software installed can simply install it themselves. It's not like it comes at extra cost, other than disk space and possibly download time, both of which would be needed for *everyone* if it was in the default installation.